# Can't get completely observed cases in each data file

Tags: r, dataframe, case, rbind

The question is asking me to write a function that reads a directory full of files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. My code works to read the data but failed to get the number of missing value for each data file. It only returns one case for all 332 files.

I think the problem may be that I only get the last complete case instead of all of them. But I don't know what method I should use in terms of my code.

```
complete<-function(directory, id=1:332){
    directory<-setwd("/Users/apple/Desktop/R coursera/specdata")
    hwData<-numeric()
    for (i in id){
            if (i<100 & i>=10){
                    hwData<-read.csv(paste("0",as.character(i),  ".csv",sep = ""), header = TRUE, sep = "", na.strings = c("NA","NAN"," "))

            }
            else if (i<10){
                    hwData<-read.csv(paste("0","0",as.character(i),".csv",sep = ""), header = TRUE, sep = "", na.strings = c("NA","NAN"," "))

            }
            else{
                    hwData<-read.csv(paste(as.character(i),".csv",sep = ""),header=TRUE,sep = "", na.strings = c("NA","NAN"," "))
            }

            nobs<-sum(complete.cases(hwData))
            dFrame<-data.frame(id,nobs=rbind(sum(complete.cases(hwData))))
    }
    return(dFrame)
}


I got:
> complete("specdata",30:25)
  id nobs
1 30 3287
2 29 3287
3 28 3287
4 27 3287
5 26 3287
6 25 3287
```

Comment: you are overwriting `dFrame`. You have to initiate it outside the loop and bind with itself + new row.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner in R. what do you mean by bind with itself + new row? do you mean use rbind?

Answer (score 0):

Initiate an empty data frame outside the loop:

```
dFrame <- data.frame()
```

And then, in loop, bind it with itself + new row:

```
dFrame <- rbind(
  dFrame, 
  data.frame(id = i, nobs = sum(complete.cases(hwData)))
)
```

Notice, that you have to assign the loop variable `i` to the id.
Check this solution and let me know if it works.